# Different MD5 hashes in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, hash, cryptography

Why hashes become different if i change input string?

My C# code is:

```
public static string CreateMD5(string strInput)
    {
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            return hashedString;
        }
    }
```

In PHP I use the `md5()` function. It is an online service so I have no source code; I just use that website to match results.

If I have this string:

```
test-server::7250406f7c43524545f794ff50dfd15b
```

Hashes are the same: `20202421c846813960404af7dd36c146`. But if I extend the string to this (with encoded characters):

```
test-server::7250406f7c43524545f794ff50dfd15b::name=%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0
```

Now hashes are different: `3db825e09eae0a83db535fda7f5ee5b5` and `ee1ae334e4bdeceb54caab15555f2f40`.

Why this happening?

Comment: Show us PHP code.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday?

Comment: The issue is the encoding, are you using the same  in `C#` and `PHP`? Have you tried `ASCII` instead of `UTF8`?

Comment: By simply looking at [this md5 online encoder](https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/), it seems like the first hash is the correct one. (just as a side note)

Comment: As for your last edit. It looks like the online service is giving you wrong hashes... Most likely because of encoding issues as stated by [Ricardo Pontual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582527/different-md5-hashes-in-php-and-c-sharp#comment88174124_50582527)

Comment: It seems that various online encoders give different hash results. Just checked some of them.

Comment: @RicardoPontual: ASCII is a very poor choice, as everything that's non-ASCII Unicode will be converted to `?`.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use md5.  It has been deprecated for 20 years yet somehow this hugely insecure hash just won't die.

Comment: Yes @Joey you're right, the intent here was just try to identify the encoding that are being used in `php`, since the code was not provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash value `ee1ae334e4bdeceb54caab15555f2f40` is the MD5 hash over `test-server::7250406f7c43524545f794ff50dfd15b::name=Инесса`. This input is the URL-decoded version of `test-server::7250406f7c43524545f794ff50dfd15b::name=%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0`.

Your C# code fragment performs MD5 on the non-decoded version. PHP decodes `GET`s by default so to get the same result you will need to double encode the value being set to the PHP script.

See here, https://3v4l.org/rK7fi (online PHP code implementation):

> The GET variables are passed through urldecode().

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Alternatively if you MD5 the value before you URL encode the values in the C# the systems should return the same hash.

Comment: you may want to add that decoded version of his data is `test-server::7250406f7c43524545f794ff50dfd15b::name=Инесса`

Comment: It seems a better idea to me to URL-decode the string in C# than to double encode it in PHP. Any reason why you chose to double encode?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I guess it isn't really double encoding, it is just encoding the partially encoded string a second time (e.g. the `name=` should also be `name%3D`.), so when it gets to the PHP it is encoded and decodes as expected. Yea, not MD5ing the URL encoded values to being with would be a better plan.

Comment: Small remark: please only use (inline) code fragments for actual code, input, output and errors and such. Do not use it to highlight "C#" or similar words. If you want to stress anything use *italics* or **bold** - but sparingly, please.